# How to convert string to code in react native?

Tags: reactjs, string, react-native

I am trying to print the image from React Native by receiving the image path from the database.

However, require() did not support dynamic paths.
Initially, the database calls up "/img/1.png". And use this "require("../assets"+"/img/1.png")" but did not work.

So I saved "require("../assets/img/1.png")" as String in DB.
but  is not working.

How can I convert String to Code?

```
let src = "require("../assets/img/1.png")";

return (
    <>
        <Image source={src} />
    </>
);
```

Comment: Actually the `require()` method returns an integer value which tells `react-native` where to look for the assets in the memory, maybe you can solve your problem by just saving name or number to image in the database and you can use them as `require('assets/images/`${name_from_db}`)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
let src = "require('../assets/img/1.png')";
```

Comment: that is not working. because "require('../assets/img/1.png')" is String.

Comment: let src = require('../assets/img/1.png'); is working.
but let src = "require('../assets/img/1.png')"; is not working

Comment: Does placing the entire Image in the variable perform the same?
let src = <Image source={require("../assets/img/1.png")} />
Then putting src in the render

Comment: The image path does not seem to work because it is the value received from DB by String.